# onManagerConnected status returning value 2 [Market error]

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface, android

```
    public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String TAG = "Test Opencv Loadback";
public static String imgPath;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
@Override
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
    switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
        }
        break;
        default: {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
        break;
    }
}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //get path from Intent
    imgPath = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PATH_NAME);
//view image using setbitmap
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_10, this, mLoaderCallback);
}
}
```

The status value is getting set to 2, even though the OpenCV manager is installed on the phone. Need help in resolving the issue.When prompted to install opencv manager, it returns package installation failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself. This was because the version code in `initAsnyc` was set to `OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_10` whereas the openCV manager version was 2.4.9. So changed the version in `initAsync` to `OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9`.